# Timing of expect() @Chisel3 Tester

Tags: chisel

I would like to confirm that timing of the iotester of chisel3. I have long time did not touch the iotester, and now I do the testing. Then I confused the timing of the output on expect().
For example;

```
val reg = RegInit(Bool(), false.B)
...
reg = !io.input
io.output = reg
```

This can be tested by iotester as follows;

```
poke(c.io.input, 0)
step(1)
expect(c.io.output, 0)//Latch the input on reg
step(1)
expect(c.io.output, 1)//Output the reg
```

Is my understanding correct?

--
NaN

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. Here's a filled out example

```
import chisel3._
import chiseltest._
import chiseltest.ChiselScalatestTester
import org.scalatest.FreeSpec

class Toggle extends MultiIOModule {
  val in = IO(Input(Bool()))
  val out = IO(Output(Bool()))

  val reg = RegInit(false.B)
  reg := ! in
  out := reg
}

class ToggleTester extends FreeSpec with ChiselScalatestTester {
  "test toggle" in {
    test(new Toggle()) { c =>
      c.in.poke(false.B)    // clock is low
      c.out.expect(false.B) // clock stil low, reg still at initial value
      c.clock.step()        // clock goes high
      c.out.expect(true.B)  // register has toggled
    }
  }
}
```

pokes take place when the clock has just gone low. 
BTW, this example is using the new chiseltest test harness. I recommend using it over the older chisel-iotesters.